# How to transpose/pivot the rows data to column in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

I am new to Spark-SQL. I have information in Spark Dataframe like this

```
Company Type Status
A       X    done
A       Y    done
A       Z    done
C       X    done
C       Y    done
B       Y    done
```

I am want to be displayed like the following

```
Company X-type Y-type Z-type
A       done    done    done
B       pending done    pending
C       done    done    pending
```

I am not able to acheive this is Spark-SQL

Please Help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can `groupby` **Company** and then use `pivot` function on column **Type**

Here is the simple example

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
        ("A", "X", "done"),
        ("A", "Y", "done"),
        ("A", "Z", "done"),
        ("C", "X", "done"),
        ("C", "Y", "done"),
        ("B", "Y", "done")
      )).toDF("Company", "Type", "Status")

val result = df.groupBy("Company")
    .pivot("Type")
    .agg(expr("coalesce(first(Status), \"pending\")"))

result.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------+----+-------+
|Company|      X|   Y|      Z|
+-------+-------+----+-------+
|      B|pending|done|pending|
|      C|   done|done|pending|
|      A|   done|done|   done|
+-------+-------+----+-------+
```

You can rename the column later.

Hope this helps!