# Pivot Dataframe with multiple columns - Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pivot

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
+----------+----+----+----+
|      date|col1|col2|col3|
+----------+----+----+----+
|2021-05-01|  20|  30|  40|
|2021-05-02| 200| 300|  10|
+----------+----+----+----+
```

I wish to pivot/transpose this dataframe as

```
+-----+----------+----------+
|col  |2021-05-01|2021-05-02|
+-----+----------+----------+
|Col1 |        20|       200|
|Col1 |        30|       300|
|Col1 |        40|        10|
+-----+----------+----------+
```

Other stackoverflow articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/how-to-pivot-spark-dataframe) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006113/how-to-transpose-pivot-the-rows-data-to-column-in-spark-scala) helped me to some extent but I have been able to reach to a solution.

My approaches were (all failed attempts)

```
scala> dUnion.groupBy("date").pivot("date").agg(first("col1")).show()
+----------+----------+----------+
|      date|2021-05-01|2021-05-02|
+----------+----------+----------+
|2021-05-02|      null|       200|
|2021-05-01|        20|      null|
+----------+----------+----------+

scala> dUnion.groupBy("date", "col1", "col2", "col3").pivot("date").agg(first("col1")).show()
+----------+----+----+----+----------+----------+
|      date|col1|col2|col3|2021-05-01|2021-05-02|
+----------+----+----+----+----------+----------+
|2021-05-02| 200| 300|  10|      null|       200|
|2021-05-01|  20|  30|  40|        20|      null|
+----------+----+----+----+----------+----------+
```

But the closet I could come up with was

```
scala> dUnion.groupBy().pivot("date").agg(first("col1")).show()
+----------+----------+
|2021-05-01|2021-05-02|
+----------+----------+
|        20|       200|
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: You are trying to unpivot. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60212279/180650

Comment: Thank you @Vitaliy. `stack` was the keyword I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This can be possible, but I think this is a bit slow.

```
val schema = df.schema
val longForm = df.flatMap(row => {
    val col = row.getString(0)
    (1 until row.size).map(i => {
        (col, schema(i).name, row.getString(i))
    })
})

longForm.groupBy('_2).pivot('_1).agg(first('_3))
.withColumnRenamed("_2", "col").show(10, false)


+----+----------+----------+
|col |2021-05-01|2021-05-02|
+----+----------+----------+
|col3|40        |10        |
|col1|20        |200       |
|col2|30        |300       |
+----+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you @Lamanus. This solution worked for me. `stack` is another way of looking at this problem and it worked for me.